# Find/Extract Emojis from Excel

Tags: excel, twitter, formula, emoji

With Twitter Archiver (TAGS), I've collected tweets like that:

> RT @LeyLaLaa: FINLAND | 8 ways to summer like the Finns in the Turku Archipelago ☀️ Sauna, lake, repeat  ... @OurFinland #ttot

I've exported the spreadsheet in Excel. Now I want to find which emojis are the most used.
For this tweet, I should have ☀️ and .
I also try to extract and count #hashtags, links, pics/videos, etc..

Any idea of the the formula?

Comment: Why not the Finnish flag as well? Are you only doing certain emojis?

Comment: There is no formula although a single UDF may be able to do multiple extracts.

Comment: @Jeeped Single UDF?

Comment: @artxtra - Pass a parameter into the UDF (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc) to Select Case and determine what is being retrieved and how the parsing is determined.